# Game console as StringBuilder, String[] or something else?

Tags: c#, string, console, stringbuilder

I'm making an XNA game console which should draw the output lines as they are added. I want to draw only the last 10 lines and I can't figure out how to produce the actual output string.

I was trying to use `StringBuilder` to collect all lines in it and then read the last lines into a `String`, but it turns out `StringBuilder` doesn't have a specific line retrieval method. I tried using `String[]`, but it adds significant lag increasing over time. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you no longer need messages older than 10 lines, you could use a typed [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx).

Depending on how you're rendering it, it might be the easiest way of managing that data.

Comment: I'd like to be able to "scroll" up and see all console lines accumulated since app launch, but for the output I'd start with 10 lines and go from there.

Comment: You have to make a trade-off then.  You can use a `List<T>` which has O(1) lookup speeds, but either O(1)-O(n) speeds upon insert (depending on whether the list has enough capacity to support a new item).  Alternatively you can use `LinkedList<T>`, which has O(1) insert speeds, but random lookup is always O(n).  The decision depends on how often you're reading vs writing.  Perhaps the best solution is to use a `LinkedList<T>`, for all messages, and a `List<T>` or `Queue<T>` for the last 10.

Comment: For now, I'll use Queue<string>(10) for output and StringBuilder to collect all data and save to file on exit, but I'd like to be able to populate the Queue with corresponding lines when "scrolling" console window.